# Check pdf restrictions with python

Tags: python, pdf, restriction

I am using python to feed pdf's to an OCR engine. However some of them may have copying restrictions. Whats the easiest way to access and check document restrictions (preferably using standard libraries, but thats not a dealbreaker)?

Comment: 4 views in 10 minutes. pdf's are evil...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyPoppler](https://launchpad.net/poppler-python/), a Python interface for the open source Poppler library.

```
import poppler
doc = poppler.document_new_from_file('file://some/file.pdf', None) # replace None with password if required
if doc.props.permissions & poppler.PERMISSIONS_OK_TO_PRINT:
     # print the file
```